# Some example of basic algorithms and frameworks used in game creation

Tags: game-design, algorithm

I understand this sounds like a broad topic, I'm asked to have those skill from one of my applied job description.  The thing is that i have been with Unity3d for 2~3 years, but I'm not really sure what are they asking for, it would be the best if you could give me a list of names or some examples to start with.

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend to create a minimum playable prototype of the most common game genres and one complete game from start to finish in your favorite one. You should then know what algorithmic knowledge a game developer needs (even if just from your decisions which corners to cut because you didn't have the time to learn the proper techniques). You will then also realize that what you need to know depends a lot on the specifics of the project. You won't need route finding in a card game or artificial intelligence in a physics puzzler.

Comment: If you are not really sure what are they asking for, you need to ask them for a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's definitely too broad, but here there are some examples of what you may need:

Algorithms

- Pathfinding algorithms, such as A*, which are the basis for AI
- Raycasting algorithms, useful for determining the line of sight, sometimes for casting shadows and bullet collisions... (Good tutorials on 2d visibility/shadow)
- (I think they are called) Flooding algorithms, search the internet for those.
- maybe all the stuff regarding collision detection and response. It's not an "algorithm" but it's fundamental. Maybe search something like 2D collision, there are quite a few tutorials. (If you want and have time you can look different approaches to the problem, such as impulse resolved collisions or speculative collisions)

Frameworks
I think the most used are:

- physics framework/engines such as Box2D, Bullet
- game structure: Artemis for example is an entity component system framework
- graphics: SDL, Qt

I don't know any of these frameworks, I prefer learning the raw algorithms, and I don't think you really should know them (they are too many), if they ask you study it, if they don't (and you don't need that for some kind of project), learn the algorithms.

Comment: If a question seems too broad, flag it as such and don't answer it. We don't want to reward users for bad behaviour.

Comment: Thank you!, sorry for the late reply, was busy with the interview, but your answer helped a bunch !